# Add property to a javascript urlSearchParams object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this piece of code that I think could be simpler, right now I'm creating an object and asigning the properties in both conditions of the if

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    var requestOptions = {}

    if(this.state.movies.length === 0 ){
        
        requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'name': this.state.name,
                'birth': this.state.birth,
                'oscars': this.state.oscars
            })
        };

    }else{

        requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'name': this.state.name,
                'birth': this.state.birth,
                'oscars': this.state.oscars,
                'movies': this.state.movies
            })
        };
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code to look like this.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  var requestOptions = {}

  const params = new URLSearchParams({
    'name': this.state.name,
    'birth': this.state.birth,
    'oscars': this.state.oscars
  });

  if (this.state.movies.length > 0) {
    params.append("movies", this.state.movies)
  }

  requestOptions.method = "POST";
  requestOptions.body = params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use Object.assign

```
new URLSearchParams(Object.assign({
  name: this.state.name,
  birth: this.state.birth,
  oscars: this.state.oscars
}, this.state.movies.length && {
  movies: this.state.name
}))
```

or create it first and conditionally append it

```
query = new URLSearchParams(Object.assign({
  name: this.state.name,
  birth: this.state.birth,
  oscars: this.state.oscars
})

this.state.movies.length && query.append('movies', this.state.movies)

requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: query
}
```